# Constructing a CDF from a discontinuous PDF

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I have a PDF that looks like the following: .25 for $0 \leq  x< .5$ and .75 for $.5 \leq x \leq 1$ (and 0 elsewhere). How do I construct a CDF from this discontinuous PDF? My instinct is to say that it should be $.25x$ for $0 \leq  x< .5$ and $.75x$ for $.5 \leq x \leq 1$, but when I integrate that over (0,1), I get a very small number (<.2) -- so I think that it must be incorrect. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the PDF you have specified is valid. To the best of my knowledge, a PDF must satistfy the constraint that $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f(x) dx = 1$ for a continuous r.v.

Your PDF is of the form:

$$f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
0.25 \quad & 0 \leq x \leq 0.5 \\
0.75 \quad & 0.5 \leq x \leq 1 \\
0 \quad &\text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$

Integrating the PDF where it is non-zero, we have that:

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} f_X(x) dx = \int^{0.5}_0 0.25 dx + \int^{1}_{0.5} 0.75 dx = \frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{8} = \frac{1}{2} \neq 1$$

So this isn't a valid PDF.